# I want to split a csv file with , and " with the latter hashigher precendence

Tags: perl, split

I want to split a csv file. ex a row contain name,id,address,pin etc..... if the adress contains again commas then how to parse? ex: Abc,123,"xyz,asd,pqr",123456            "xyz,asd,pqr" is one element and kept in double quotes only

Answer (score 0):

Use a [CSV parser](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV). If you don't want to install new modules for some reason then look at [Text::ParseWords](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::ParseWords) instead.